# Receiving Segmentation Fault 11 error after calling function in a constructor definition?

Tags: c++, function, class, segmentation-fault, class-constructors

I've researched this error and it seems common with dangerous memory allocation or overload, but I can't find where that applies to my code. Basically I keep receiving the error message:

> Segmentation fault: 11

every time I run my code after calling my **simplify** function in the parameterized Fraction constructor definition. And it's funny, because when I call the **change** function inside this definition, it's completely ignored. I'm trying to figure out how to get **change** to at least work so I can figure out how to properly apply **simplify**, but I've been at this for ages and am still at a loss.

I have three files: fraction.h, fraction.cpp, and main.cpp. Main.cpp was written by my professor -- this is an assignment for creating header and implementation files to allow his code to run. Instructions for this particular part are:

> A private member function called **simplify** that reduces the fraction to
>   its lowest terms (12/15 => 4/5). If you write the function, you should call the **simplify** function within the parameterized constructor definition, so that the function is created in simplified form.

//fraction.h :

```
#ifndef FRACTION_
#define FRACTION_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Fraction {

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    int change (int a, int b);
    Fraction simplify (int n, int d);

public:

    Fraction();

    Fraction (int num, int denom);

    Fraction sumWith (Fraction a);

    Fraction multiplyWith (Fraction z);

    void const print (ostream & out) const;

};

#endif /* defined(____Fraction__) */
```

//fraction.cpp [excluding the unaffected functions]:

```
#include "fraction.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int Fraction::change(int a, int b){
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    return temp; }

Fraction Fraction::simplify (int n, int d){
    int r, gcd, true_n, true_d, q;

    true_n = n;
    true_d = d;

    if ((n) < (d)){
        change (n, d);
        q = 5; }

    r = (n % d);

    if ((r != 1) && (r != 0)){
        for (int i = 0; r > 1; i++){
            r = (n % d);
            d = n;
            r = d;
            i++; }

        if (r == 0){
            gcd = n;
            n = true_n/gcd;
            d = true_d/gcd; }

        else {
            n = true_n;
            d = true_d; }
    }

    if (r == 0){
        n = n/d;
        d = 1; }

    if (q == 5){
        change (n, d); }

    return Fraction(n, d); }

Fraction::Fraction() {
    numerator = 1;
    denominator = 1; }


Fraction::Fraction (int num, int denom) {

        if (denom == 0) {
            cerr << "Denominator may not be 0.";
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
        else {
            numerator = num;
            denominator = denom; }

        if (denominator < 0){
            denominator = denominator * -1;
            numerator = numerator * -1; }

    simplify (numerator, denominator);
}
```

//applicable excerpt of main.cpp :

```
void outputExpression(ostream & out,
                      const Fraction & num1,
                      const Fraction & num2,
                      const Fraction & result,
                      bool isSum);

int main() {
    Fraction num1, num2, result;

    num1 = Fraction(1, 2);
    num2 = Fraction(2, 3);
    result = num1.sumWith(num2);
    outputExpression(cout, num1, num2, result, true);
    result = num1.multiplyWith(num2);
    outputExpression(cout, num1, num2, result, false);
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger to locate the crash? And if it happens in some library code, go `up` the call stack until you're in your code.

Comment: What's the point of `change()`? It just returns `a`. If you meant it to swap the values, then you need to pass references in: `int& a`. Or just use the standard library's `swap` function.

Comment: When an error occurs in a constructor, throw and exception instead of calling exit.

Comment: The `change` function doesn't do what you think it does. Remember that when passing arguments by value, the values are *copied* and the function only works on the copies. If you want to swap two values use e.g. [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), or at least change your function to take the arguments by reference.

Comment: For future reference, closing braces belong on their own lines.

Comment: Also, your call to `simplify` at the bottom of the constructor does nothing. `simplify` returns a new `Fraction` object, but that call ignores the return value.

Comment: ... and that construction of a new Fraction calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify which constructs a new Fraction which calls simplify

Answer (score 1):

I read your code exactly and find out your scenario for writing this code ,
there some problems in your code that is serious:
1- definition of function change must be in bellow format:

```
int Fraction::change(int* a, int* b){
int temp;
temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
return *temp; }
```

2- in your constructor you call simplify function,

```
simplify (numerator, denominator);
```

also in your simplify function, you call fraction constructor:

```
simplify (numerator, denominator);
```

it is an infinite loop that will cause excessive (extra from legal amount of one program for using heap) use of heap space.

3 - in simplify function, you write:

```
if ((r != 1) && (r != 0)){
    for (int i = 0; r > 1; i++){
        r = (n % d);
        d = n;
        r = d;
        i++; }
```

this is a problem because you must save d in a temp variable before d=n;

otherwise next command (r = d;) will be equivalent by r = n;

you must solve this logical errors for solving fragmentation error.
this error in caused in this case:

when a program use large space of heap that is larger than its legal amount of heap use.
in some cases that generating object or getting memory (alloc | malloc) fall in infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you have:

```
Fraction::Fraction (int num, int denom) {
    // ...
    simplify (numerator, denominator);
}
```

Then, in `simplify` you have:

```
Fraction Fraction::simplify (int n, int d){
    // ...
    return Fraction(n, d);
}
```

That is an infinite loop.

You can fix it in one of two ways:

- If you do not want to allow unsimplified fractions, then make `simplify` modify the object instead of returning a new one.

like this:

```
numerator = n;
denominator = d;
```

- Your current `simplify` is basically a builder method. You pass it an `n` and `d` and it returns a simplified `Fraction` for you. Such methods should be `static`. You should not call `simplify` inside the constructor, but instead declare it `static` and use it like this: `num1 = Fraction::simplify(1, 2);`